# What are the possible cases when Kafka consumer offset got reset?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

What are the possible cases when Kafka consumer offset got reset? We are not able to find good documentation around offset reset. This can give us a good idea about offset management in Kafka

We have seen one case when all Kafka brokers got crashed due to disk space and we restarted all broker but one of the Kafka brokers with the new log location. In that case, we have seen that all topics data replicated back but consumer offset got reset for all topics where the offset is stored in the __consumer_offset topic of Kafka.

This does not happen where offset was stored in zookeeper. In those cases, everything works normally. What could be the reason of this offset reset?